# upload photo to album on facebook with FB.api javascript?

Tags: facebook

Im trying to upload a photo to one of my albums on facebook, with the below code, but no upload and now error?
What are I missing?
I have a album thats called Loggfoton where I want the photos to end up, or if there is no album at all, then that one is created.

> function uploadphoto(){
>   var imgURL =
>   "http://www.mydomain.se/armani1.jpg";
>
> ```
>     FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
>         message: 'photo description',
>         access_token: accessToken, 
>         url: imgURL
>     }, function (response) {
>
>         if (!response || response.error) {
>             alert('Error occured:' + response);
>         } else {
>             alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
>         }
>
>     });           }
> ```

Any input really appeciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "**/album_id/photos**" as url:

```
function uploadphoto(){
    var imgURL = "http://www.mydomain.se/armani1.jpg";

    FB.api('/album_id/photos', 'post', {
        message:'photo description',
        url:imgURL        
    }, function(response){
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Sudhir and thanks, but now I get an error: (object Object)?

Comment: And also how can I upload images to a specific album?
How much text can I have in a message when I upload a image?

Comment: ok, now I can upload images, I wrote my facebook id no instead of album_id and now it uploads. Good!
But still, how can I upload to a specific album?

Comment: Can we show photo inside share dialog and use it for sharing image and not the link?